# jQuery content panel switcher prevents from accessing form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery.content-panel-switcher for a top menu in my site. It shows and hides different forms such as

```
 <div id="switcher-panel"></div>

            <!-- form to add, later do import here -->

            <div id="adds-content" class="switcher-content set1 show">
                <form action='/post' name='submitform' id="submitform" method='post' class='pure-form'>

                        <textarea columns="40" rows="4" name='entry[body]' id="statement" placeholder='enter a note here to visualize the words and their connections, you can also use #hashtags and @mentions.'><% if (url) { %><%= urltitle %> <%= url %> @bookmarks<% } %></textarea>
                        <div id="addToContextsLabel">contexts:</div>
                        <ul id="addToContexts"></ul>
                        <input type="hidden" id="addedContexts" name="addedContexts">
                        <input type="hidden" id="context" name="context" value="<%= context %>">
                        <input type="hidden" id="selectedContexts" name="selectedContexts" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="statementid" value="">
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        <input type='submit' name="submit" id="submitbutton" value="save" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">

                </form>

            </div>

            <!-- form to find -->

            <div id="finds-content" class="switcher-content set1">

                <form class="pure-form" id="searchform">
                    <input type="text" id="search" size="17" maxlength="20" class="pure-input" placeholder="search...">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type='submit' name="submit" value="find" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">

                </form>
            </div>
```

Now when I try to access elements using             `document.submitform.submit.value = "edit";` it simply doesn't work even if the form shows up in my browser.

Do you know what the problem could be?

Thanks!

Comment: same as last question on this, you need to show more code to see why it isn't working. A demo in jsfiddle.net would really help. Code shown works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/3r6ykm4t/

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was that `document.submitform` was using the div elements as they were loaded by the browser. However, the `jquery.content-panel-switcher` js module was rendering those invisible because it simply copies them into another div after the page is loaded.

So what I had to do was to access the actual elements created by jquery.content-panel-switcher using jquery and then it worked fine.